# Вопрос по ООП. Конкретный пример.

Tags: ооп

Моделирую игровую ситуацию: Есть стол(отдельный класс), есть 4 игрока(отдельные классы, из обьекты созданы внутри класса стола) и у каждого на руках есть несколько карт. Мне нужно, чтобы каждый из игроков мог видеть какрты других и для этого я хочу поступить таки образом: Я буду подавать в класс игрока класс стола и у меня получится что они будут содержать в себе друг друга, это плохое ООП:) Какие варианты я могу еще реализовать?

Comment: почитайте про шаблон медиатор

Comment: Реквестирую кусок кода, будет намного более дельная дискуссия. Если это еще актуально, конечно же.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Иметь ссылку -- не значит содержать.

Вполне нормальная схема: стол *содержит* коллекцию игроков, игрок *знает о* столе, за которым сидит, и соответственно *видит* остальных игроков, а значит, и их *открытые* карты.

Всё это моделируется ссылками на объекты, открытые карты моделируются свойством, доступным только на чтение.

Comment: С последним дополнением идея нравится больше. Спасибо

Comment: @alex91: Пожалуйста!

Comment: У меня такая иерархия. 
Стол - > Игрок - > Карты
Я пропишу в игроке Стол как доступный только на чтение. Это будет распространяться на карты? Или я так понимаю нет и лучше тогда передать не весь Стол, а только коллекцию с игроками.

Comment: @alex91: Зависит, конечно, от языка, но я бы сделал в любом случае открытые карты неизменяемой снаружи коллекцией неизменяемых объектов. Потому что мало ли кто и откуда будет иметь доступ к игроку, каждый раз думать, константная ли ссылка на игрока, не объектно-ориентировано как-то.

Comment: C#. Решил передать коллекцию как рид онли.

Comment: Не слишком костыльно?

Comment: Только у вас должно быть

    class Card : IReadOnlyCard

и тогда вы выставляете наружу

    public IEnumerable<IReadOnlyCard> OpenCards
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<IReadOnlyCard>(cards);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Более гибкая структура классов будет чуть сложнее. Надо разделить набор карт (называется Рука) и игрока который ими играет:

- Рука (набор карт, знает о картах)
- Стол (знает руки. ведет розыгрыш)
- Игрок (видит стол, видит другие руки, управляет своей рукой или руками (если может играть за 2+))
- Игра (знает всех игроков, стол)

При таком подходе каждый уровень знает только то, что ему положено и не смотрит вверх. Т.о. логика рук не знает о столе (сколько игроков, каких) или, тем более, об игроке (бот это, сетевой игрок, и т.п.). Также, при дополнительной доработке, один игрок может управлять несколькими руками (например в преферансе это часто бывает нужно), или быть зрителем (игроком без руки).